# Google Drive does not work after a reboot

Tags: mount, kde, google-drive

Just transferred to Linux. My distro - KDE Neon. Based on Ubuntu.

I installed Google Drive Using google drive ocamlfuse by this guide:

https://linoxide.com/tools/how-use-google-drive-ubuntu-linux/

Now, when I reboot my system, Google Drive does not work (it does not sync to my created folder) and I have to manually run the command

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/Google\ Drive
```

every time I restart my computer in order for Google Drive to properly work.

Why do I have to run it every time after reboot and how do to that I would not need to run that command after a reboot?

Comment: Use rclone...it's much better

Comment: how is it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire it up at boot using a systemd service.  Three easy steps.

(1) create the service file. You will need root privs, so use sudo.
Replace the "User" and the directory argument on the "ExecStart" line, unless your name is Paul.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/google-drive-ocamlfuse.service
[Unit]
Description=Start GoogleDrive ocamlfuse at boot
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=paul
ExecStart=/usr/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/paul/GoogleDrive


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then (2) start it, and (3) enable it at boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl start google-drive-ocamlfuse
$ sudo systemctl enable google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Please let me know if you run into any issues.